# What are the consequences of the angular momentum of the electron in an atom?

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum, electrons, atomic-physics

Well, since the electron is going around the nucleus, it must have an angular momentum (plus its spin). And since it is charged it must create an electric field. If  I have understood it correctly it is the interaction with this field that is causing the so-called Anomalous [Zeeman effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeeman_effect)?

Is this correct?

And does does this have any other consequences?

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the [fine structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure) of atomic spectra, and particularly with its spin-orbit component.

Comment: Check this....http://web.phys.ntu.edu.tw/asc/FunPhysExp/ModernPhys/exp/ZeemanEffect.pdf

Answer (score 1):

An electron revolving in the atomic orbit gives rise to an electric current which is equivalent to a magnetic shell of magnetic moment $\mu_l$. We can calculate this magnetic moment in this way:-
Time period of electron is $T=\frac{2\pi r}{v}$;  So, equivalent current $I=\frac{q}{T}=\frac{qv}{2\pi r}$
Hence magnetic moment, $\mu_l=I.A=\frac{qv}{2\pi r}.\pi r^2=\frac{q}{2m}mvr=\frac{q}{2m}L$, where $L$ is angular momentum of the charge particle.

Now charge of an electron, $q=-e$.    So, $\mu_l=-\frac{e}{2m}L;  $ 
According to Bohr's theory $L=\hbar m_l$, where $m_l$ is integer.

$\therefore$ $\mu_l=m_l (\frac{e\hbar}{2mv})=m_l\mu_B$ where $\mu_B$ is Bohr magneton.
If we placed the atom in an external magnetic field energy level split into $m_l$ levels where $m_l$ takes both +ve and -ve values. This is called normal 
Zeeman effect.
In case of anomalous Zeeman effect we have to take spin of electron in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on explanations like [this one](http://www.nyu.edu/classes/tuckerman/quant.mech/lectures/lecture_5/node3.html). Yes, it is caused by the interaction with the magnetic field. "Tt suggests the possible existence of an angular momentum like quantity that can take on half-integer values." As a consequence, there may be a singlet-type fine structure spectrum as well.